# Django - annotate with multiple Count

Tags: django, django-models, django-annotate

I have a model called `Post` which has two fields `upvotes` and `downvotes`. Now, `upvotes`, `downvotes` are `ManyToManyField` to a `Profile`. This is the model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    subreddit = models.ForeignKey(Subreddit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='upvoted_posts')
    downvotes = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, blank=True, related_name='downvoted_posts')
```

So, I want to fetch all the posts such that they are in the order of

**`total(upvotes) - total(downvotes)`**

So I have used this query:

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    total_votes=Count('upvotes')-Count('downvotes')
).order_by('total_votes')
```

The problem with this query is the `total_votes` is always turning out to be **zero**.

The below queries will explain the situation:

```
In [5]: Post.objects.annotate(up=Count('upvotes')).values('up')
Out[5]: <QuerySet [{'up': 1}, {'up': 3}, {'up': 2}]>

In [6]: Post.objects.annotate(down=Count('downvotes')).values('down')
Out[6]: <QuerySet [{'down': 1}, {'down': 1}, {'down': 1}]>

In [10]: Post.objects.annotate(up=Count('upvotes'), down=Count('downvotes'), total=Count('upvotes')-Count('downvotes')).values('up', 'down', 'total')
Out[10]: <QuerySet [{'up': 1, 'down': 1, 'total': 0}, {'up': 3, 'down': 3, 'total': 0}, {'up': 2, 'down': 2, 'total': 0}]>
```

Seems like both `up` and `down` are having the same value(which is actually the value of `up`). How can I solve this?

I have tried this:

```
In [9]: Post.objects.annotate(up=Count('upvotes')).annotate(down=Count('downvotes')).values('up', 'down')
Out[9]: <QuerySet [{'up': 1, 'down': 1}, {'up': 3, 'down': 3}, {'up': 2, 'down': 2}]>
```

but even this gives the same output.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have a many-to-many to a profile, and store in the m2m table whether it is an upvote/downvote?

Comment: Yes, It is a ManyToMany with Profile and I think Django handles that table that you are talking about!!

Comment: correct, but you can define the `through` table, and thus add attributes to the relation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to use [`dictinct`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) argument:

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    total_votes=Count('upvotes', distinct=True)-Count('downvotes', distinct=True)
).order_by('total_votes')
```

From the docs:

> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong
>   results because joins are used instead of subqueries. For most
>   aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however, the Count
>   aggregate has a distinct parameter that may help.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm aware that this isn't exactly an answer, but code can't be embedded in a comment.)

A better data model would be

```
class Post:
  # ...

class Vote:
  voter = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  score = models.IntegerField()  # either -1 or +1; validate accordingly

  class Meta:
    unique_together = [('voter', 'post'),]
```

This way you could count the current total score for a post simply with

```
Vote.objects.filter(post=post).aggregate(score=Sum('score'))
```

However, you should be well aware of the performance implications of doing this (or your original version for that matter) every time.  It would be better to add a

```
score = models.IntegerField(editable=False)
```

field to the `Post`, that gets updated with the aggregate score every time a vote is created, modified or deleted.