# django annotate count is giving wrong output

Tags: django, django-models, backend, django-database

Suppose

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    ...
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User,...)
```

```
class Post
    ...
    content = models.CharField(...)
    likes = models.ManyToManyFiled(User,...)
    comment = models.ManyToManyField(Comment,...)
```

Now if I run

**Statement1**

```
Post.objects.annotate(likecount=Count('likes')).values('content','likecount')
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [{'content': 'delta', 'likecount': 3}, {'content': 'gamma', 'likecount': 6}, {'content': 'beta', 'likecount': 7}, {'content': 'alpha', 'likecount': 3}]>
```

**Statement2**

```
Post.objects.annotate(commentlikecount=Count('comment__likes')).values('content','commentlikecount')
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [{'content': 'delta', 'commentlikecount': 6}, {'content': 'gamma', 'commentlikecount': 0}, {'content': 'beta', 'commentlikecount': 3}, {'content': 'alpha', 'commentlikecount': 0}]>
```

**Statement3**

```
Post.objects.annotate(likecount=Count('likes'),commentlikecount=Count('comment__likes')).values('content','likecount','commentlikecount')
```

Output:

```
<QuerySet [{'content': 'delta', 'likecount': 18, 'commentlikecount': 18}, {'content': 'gamma', 'likecount': 6, 'commentlikecount': 0}, {'content': 'beta', 'likecount': 21, 'commentlikecount': 21}, {'content': 'alpha', 'likecount': 3, 'commentlikecount': 0}]>
```

Why the output of third statement is this instead of

```
<QuerySet [{'content': 'delta', 'likecount': 3, 'commentlikecount': 6}, {'content': 'gamma', 'likecount': 6, 'commentlikecount': 0}, {'content': 'beta', 'likecount': 7, 'commentlikecount': 3}, {'content': 'alpha', 'likecount': 3, 'commentlikecount': 0}]>
```

How can i have this as output?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701091/django-annotate-with-multiple-count

Comment: You make two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s, hence the two joins act as a multiplier.